# base64_encode more than 1 time

Tags: php, base64

Is it possible to create a PHP script that will base64_encode another PHP file 50 times ?

I already tried to encode a PHP script 2 times manually using base64_encode ... and now when I tried to decode the 2nd script, it returns the first base64 encoded file (so it works)...

More information: I want to create a PHP script that will base64_encode the file "myfile.php" (myfile.php is on the same directory where the PHP script which I want to create exists) ... So if myfile.php was encoded I want this code:

```
<?php
base64_decode(BLABLABLA);
?>
```

to be encoded again ( for 50 times ).

Thanks.

Comment: Just execute base64_encode 50 times in a loop? Or am I missing a subtlety here?

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) { base64_encode("blah"); }`?

Comment: @Bytewave - I don't know. but it seems the same I want to do it. But how to encode a PHP file using base64_encode instead of a text using this method?

Comment: @fvu - I wouldn't ask this question of course if the answer was like that.

Comment: @protld Ahh. See [`file_get_contents`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) then.

Comment: @Bytewave - And should I use something to execute that, or it is automatically executed upon the browse of the script? And how the output will be? in a file or upon browsing the script in the browser?

Comment: @protld I'm not quite sure what you mean. When you call a PHP script, either via the CLI or a web server, its contents are executed. You just need to set up your web server, point it at the right directory, and send your browser to the PHP script.

Comment: @Bytewave - What about the output (result) ... how will I get it?

Comment: so you plan on decoding it 50 times also? what's the purpose of this?

Comment: @protld Just [`echo`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) it? ie: `$res = file_get_contents("blah"); for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) { $res = base64_encode($res); } echo $res;`

Comment: @Bytewave - Can you post that as an answer? I want to select it as the marked one! :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a loop and `echo` the result.

Encoding:

```
$result = file_get_contents("path/to/file.ext");

for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
    $result = base64_encode($result);
}

echo $result;
```

To decode, just replace `base64_encode` with `base64_decode`.